# Почему overflow даёт такой эффект?

Tags: css3

Я в непонятках...Учусь иногда на "w3school", и тут мне попался один пример:
Меня заинтересовало для чего тут свойство overflow:hidden, ну я его стёр чтоб проверить.В результате: страница вывода стала пустой(менюшка пропала).Я начал лазить искать:почему? Но о таких свойствах overflow ничего нигде не написано,оно лишь скрывает лишнее у объекта. Что к чему, кто знает?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333333;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #111111;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ничего не пропало, просто у тебя шрифт белый. Наведи мышку и фон поменяется. А ответ на вопрос - clearfix.

Comment: Во блин... Но почему-тогда фон пропал, я ж не фон удалял.

Comment: Вам бы про float почитать - тогда поймете почему так происходит.

Comment: Всё равно ничего не понял,бред какой-то. Есть цвет фона,есть float:left, при чём тут overflow:hidden ? что он прячет ? Почему без него цвет фона не работает ?

Comment: добавили для сброса обтекания float-а

Comment: И всё-таки, погугли clearfix...